# Get Time to first byte from API Groovy

Tags: api, groovy, katalon, time-to-first-byte

I am writing a script to get TTFB for an URL. This getResponseCode method gives me status code for the URL. What method or formula can I use to get TTFB after connection is established?

HttpURLConnection connection

```
    try {
        
            URL url = new URL('www.xyx.com')
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection()
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET")
            connection.connect()

            println(connection.getResponseCode())
        
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        return 0
    }
    finally {
        connection.disconnect()
                    }
```

Comment: What exactly you don't know? How to measure time? Or how to get first byte from stream?

Comment: How can I get TTFB using a program? I can see TTFB in chrome devtools but I want it as the output from my program. Is there a method in connection library ?

Comment: No such a method in standard java.net package.

Comment: can I calculate is using existing methods or get it from devtools somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way

```js
long t0 = System.getTimeMillis()
connection.getInputStream()?.read()
long t1 = System.getTimeMillis()

long ttfb = t1 - t0
```

However I'm not sure about accuracy...

Comment: Retrieving the stream (`getInputStream()`) probably shouldn't be done inside the timer.  The same thing for the null check.

Comment: Probably you are right. I would wrap it into @CompileStatic to minimize dynamic groovy latency.

Comment: "I would wrap it into @CompileStatic to minimize dynamic groovy latency." - If you did, I still think it makes sense to call `getInputStream()` and do any null checking before the timer starts.